# My Legacy java web application Servlet accepts only HTTP requests, I want to change it to accept HTTPS request. Please suggest

Tags: java

Current Issue: MyServlet class only accepts HTTP request, want to Fix to accept HTTPS requests.
As I am moving my application to PCF/cloud Env. by creating Docker Image of legacy application).
Please suggest code changes to accept MyServlet request in HTTPS only ?
Since I have to move this to PCF so all request will be https request and current servlet accepts
http servlet request.

Any suggestion with minimal code changes will help a lot to resolve it and thanks a lot in
advance !!

Please see I already updated web.xml for CONFIDENTIAL
from NONE. But it still unable to accept https request and i also check web browser which is
enable for TLS1.2 enable checked in IE along with other 1.1... 3.1 etc.

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Public Area</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Public Area</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/ApplicationProbe.jsp</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
       <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>  
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Request Servlet looks like -

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
     
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet{
    
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException{
        processIt(req, resp);}
 
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException{
        processIt(req, resp);}
        
    private void processIt(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException{
            String errMsg = null;
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = null;
        
            logger = Logger.getLogger(MyServlet.class);
            
            //get request parameters 
            String sourceParam = req.getParameter("param_1");
        
            //.....other code flows  
            }
           //.....code 
}
```

Comment: Any HTTPS stuff is usually handled by your servlet container or application server, not your Servlet or `.war`. Take a look at how you can configure your application server to allow HTTPS and disallow HTTP.

Comment: For example IF you're using Tomcat 9 see https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/http.html . Note that whatever sw you use you'll need a privatekey and a matching certificate (with chain if applicable) either from a real CA that your browser(s) trust like LetsEncrypt, Digicert, GoDaddy OR a self-signed cer that you _add_ to your browser(s) as trusted.

Comment: Thanks for information ..I Checked my tomcat container server file which has an entry <Connector connectionTimeout="5000" port="8085" protocol="HTTP/1.1" maxThreads="500" redirectPort="8485"/> to run from local and i try change it to add additional properties ... SSLEnabled="true" clientAuth="false" maxThreads="500" scheme="https" secure="true" sslProtocol="SSL"  etc. but it stop in launching server itself. Please see i am using tomcat container 7.0.55/81